# escape sequence with for a combination of \ and ’ in python

Tags: python, escaping, sequence

I would like to have in a file g a text like

```
stat.run('Export RStd \'distFunc.txt\' overwrite')
```

I am using variations of

```
g.write("stat.run('Export RStd \ ")
g.write("'distFunc.txt\")
g.write("' overwrite')\n")
```

however, due to escape sequence and \'  the code is not working. I have tried alot of varieties and one liner was not possible for me. So I tried to divide it to three lines and parse it but still that escape sequence is problematic! 
Can anybody suggest a way to do it?
regards

Comment: _" the code is not working"_. So, are you getting an error message, or...?

Comment: just do `stat.run("Export RStd 'distFunc.txt' overwrite")` you won't have to escape the quotes by using double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use raw string (prefixed by `r`) and triple quotes (a sequence of three `'` or `"` characters in a row). Inside a raw string, backslashes are not magic. Inside a triple-quoted string, neither single quotes nor double quotes are magic. The following two complete programs are equivalent:

```
with open ("g", "w") as g:
    g.write(r'''stat.run('Export RStd \'distFunc.txt\' overwrite')''')
```

```
with open ("g", "w") as g:
    g.write(r"""stat.run('Export RStd \'distFunc.txt\' overwrite')""")
```

Or, use raw strings with double quotes. Inside a double-quoted string, single quotes aren't magic:

```
with open ("g", "w") as g:
    g.write(r"stat.run('Export RStd \'distFunc.txt\' overwrite')")
```

Or, if you don't want to use raw strings, you can escape the backslashes:

```
with open ("g", "w") as g:
    g.write("stat.run('Export RStd \\'distFunc.txt\\' overwrite')")
```

Finally, if you must use a single-quoted string, you can escape the single quotes:

```
with open ("g", "w") as g:
    g.write('stat.run(\'Export RStd \\\'distFunc.txt\\\' overwrite\')')
```

Please realize that each of the above lines of source code name precisely the same string. Even though they are represented differently in the source, all of the resulting strings are equal:

```
assert (
    r'''stat.run('Export RStd \'distFunc.txt\' overwrite')''' ==
    r"""stat.run('Export RStd \'distFunc.txt\' overwrite')""" ==
    r"stat.run('Export RStd \'distFunc.txt\' overwrite')" ==
    "stat.run('Export RStd \\'distFunc.txt\\' overwrite')" ==
    'stat.run(\'Export RStd \\\'distFunc.txt\\\' overwrite\')')
```

Comment: can you please explain that a bit? it would be helpful for later implementations. Regards!